# can one get lossless access to iOS camera?

Tags: iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: Get pixel-by-pixel data from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865100/ios-get-pixel-by-pixel-data-from-camera)
>   [Raw image data from camera like “645 PRO”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612647/raw-image-data-from-camera-like-645-pro)

is there access to control iOS camera and get raw pixel information from it - i.e. lossless access to camera?

It is essential that the raw data be recovered from multiple frames for subsequent processing.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera). You'll need to use the AVFoundation, CoreMedia and CoreVideo frameworks.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865100/ios-get-pixel-by-pixel-data-from-camera