# UIImageviewPicker - For Raw image and avfoundation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In `UIImageviewPicker` - The photo i am capturing ,

is that delegate is using AVFoundation framework for taking photo ?
The image I am getting , If I want RAW (not JPEG/PNG) image , Can I use the same image I am getting from

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

this info dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably UIImagePicker camera grabbing is based on AVFoundation. The image given in the info dictionary is not RAW. If you want a row image you should implement your own camera functionalities using foundation and accessing the CVSampleBuffer.
Check also this answer [iOS: Get pixel-by-pixel data from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865100/ios-get-pixel-by-pixel-data-from-camera)